# Convert Join Oracle Syntax with DB2

Tags: join, oracle11g, db2

i have a query in Oracle with (+) operator.

```
SELECT * FROM
VEICOLO V,
DISPOSIZIONE DIS,
ASSEGNAZIONE ASS,
UFFICIO U,
USCITA US,
FERMOVEICOLO FV,
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        PARAMETRI
    WHERE
        DOMINIO='TIPOISTITUTO' ) P,
COMUNE C1,
MODELLO MO,
MARCA MA,
PARAMETRI P1,
PARAMETRI P2 WHERE MO.CODICE_MARCA = MA.CODICE_MARCA 
AND (MO.TIPOUTILIZZO = P1.CODIFICA OR P1.CODIFICA IS NULL) 
AND (P1.DOMINIO = 'TIPOUTILIZZO' OR P1.DOMINIO IS NULL) 
AND MO.TIPOMEZZO = P2.CODIFICA AND P2.DOMINIO = 'TIPOMEZZO' 
AND (U.TIPOISTITUTO = P.CODIFICA OR P.CODIFICA IS NULL) AND (C1.CODICE_COMUNE = U.CODICE_COMUNE OR C1.CODICE_COMUNE IS NULL) AND    V.CODICE_MODELLO=MO.CODICE_MODELLO AND (V.CODICE_VEICOLO=DIS.CODICE_VEICOLO(+))
AND DIS.STATODISPOSIZIONE (+)<> 'C' AND V.CODICE_VEICOLO=ASS.CODICE_VEICOLO (+)
AND ASS.DATAFINE (+) IS NULL AND ASS.CODICE_UFFICIO = U.CODICE_UFFICIO (+)
AND V.CODICE_VEICOLO = FV.CODICE_VEICOLO (+) AND V.CODICE_VEICOLO = US.CODICE_VEICOLO (+) AND FV.DATARITORNODISPONIBILITA (+) IS NULL
AND NOT US.DATAUSCITA (+) IS NULL AND V.TARGA LIKE '181%'
```

This query in Oracle return 5 records.

I convert this query in DB2 with LEFT JOIN / RIGHT JOIN, but return only 1 record.
Where is the problem ?

```
SELECT * FROM modello mo INNER JOIN marca ma ON mo.codice_marca = ma.codice_marca INNER JOIN veicolo v ON v.codice_modello = mo.codice_modello LEFT OUTER JOIN disposizione dis ON v.codice_veicolo = dis.codice_veicolo AND dis.statodisposizione <> 'C' LEFT OUTER JOIN assegnazione ass ON v.codice_veicolo = ass.codice_veicolo AND ass.datafine IS NULL LEFT OUTER JOIN fermoveicolo fv ON v.codice_veicolo = fv.codice_veicolo AND fv.DATARITORNODISPONIBILITA IS NULL LEFT OUTER JOIN uscita us ON v.codice_veicolo = us.codice_veicolo AND NOT us.datauscita IS NULL INNER JOIN parametri p2 ON mo.tipomezzo = p2.codifica LEFT OUTER JOIN parametri p1 ON mo.tipoutilizzo = p1.codifica AND p1.dominio = 'TIPOUTILIZZO' LEFT OUTER JOIN ufficio u ON ass.codice_ufficio = u.codice_ufficio LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT * FROM PARAMETRI WHERE DOMINIO='TIPOISTITUTO') p ON u.tipoistituto = p.codifica RIGHT OUTER JOIN comune c1 ON c1.codice_comune = u.codice_comune WHERE p2.dominio = "TIPOMEZZO";
```

Comment: 1. Use Oracle to test query with explicit joins.
2. Convert each (+) operator to explicit join one by one

Query is too large to search for an error ad hoc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was "TIPOMEZZO". Correct version is 'TIPOMEZZO'.
Thanks.
Vincenzo